# Issue with html css bullet list vertical

Tags: list, html-lists, nav

The HTML:

```
<ul class="fruits">
<li>Peach</li>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Banana</li>
<li>Pineapple</li>
<li>Strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.fruits ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

.fruits ul li
{
background-image:url('http://www.myurl.co.uk/images/mybullet.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0px 5px; 
padding-left:14px;
}
```

I have other horizontal navigation menus on the page so this needs to be classed as above. When I attempt to try, it defaults back to a bullet list only, and doesn't work. I tried only using < ul > and it worked, but messed the rest of the page up. Any suggestions for a normal vertical bullet list with specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul.fruits
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

I have made a jsfiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xsceB/). I have removed the background styles so don't forget to re-insert them.